# Improve performance pushing to custom singly linked list

Tags: java, data-structures

I created a singly linked list in java. This list has the property that the first item pushed is the last item that will be popped.

The popping performance is nice compared to the Queue. I like to improve the push performance. Instead of prepending I also tried appending in the push method, this didn't improve the performance.

Do you guys have any idea how to improve this list?

Push-Pop performance (Stack, ArrayList and Queue are the java.util implementations):

10 million integers averaged over 10 runs

- Stack filling: 776.3ms
- Stack popping: 207.2ms
- ArrayList filling: 574.0ms
- ArrayList popping: 35.3ms
- Queue filling: 2642.2ms
- Queue popping: 96.9ms
- MyList filling: 4811.2ms
- MyList popping: 50.5ms

```java
public class MyList<T> {
    T head = null;
    MyList<T> tail = null;
    boolean isNil = true;

    public T pop() {
        if(isNil) {
            return null;
        }
        else if(this.tail.isNil) {
            this.isNil = true;
            return head;
        }
        else {
            T head = this.head;
            this.head = this.tail.head;
            this.tail = this.tail.tail;
            return head;
        }
    }

    public void push(T element) {
        MyList<T> item = new MyList<T>();
        item.head = this.head;
        item.tail = this.tail;
        item.isNil = this.isNil;
        this.head = element;
        this.tail = item;
        this.isNil = false;
    }
}
```

Comment: I would use the standard, already existing, well-tested, integrated into the collections framework, data structures. The performance gain you might gain will probably be ridiculous compared to the ones you would gain in a real application by tuning queries, reducing inter-process calls, or using an O(n) algorithm rather than a O(n^2) one.

Comment: @JBNizet while it wasn't sepcifically stated in the question, I suspect this is a homework assignment. There aren't many real world use-cases for a single linked list that a double linked list wouldn't also work for... There's a reason there isn't an implementation of it in the standard libraries.

Comment: The terminology you are misusing for the names of the members makes it hard to read the source. It would honestly be easier to read if you just named them a and b, instead of head (which really works as value) and tail (which is used as next/succ).

Comment: I used the terminology used in scala, here the head is the item on top of the list and the tail is the remaining list.

Answer (score 1):

Changing the test below to use ArrayList<Integer> I get the following when I use a large young generation size. `-XX:NewSize=1g`  This helps because GC is a major overhead and a large Eden size reduces the number of GCs.

```
ArrayList push&pop 10000000 repeated 10 times took 1183 ms.
```

Note: for ArrayList to be efficient you want to be adding to the end, (and removing from the end)

---

You can try TIntArrayList or do the same

```
TIntArrayList list = new TIntArrayList();
long start = System.nanoTime();
int values = 10 * 1000 * 1000;
int runs = 10;
for (int r = 0; r < runs; r++) {
    for (int i = 0; i < values; i++) {
        list.add(i);
    }
    for (int i = 0; i < values; i++) {
        int last = list.remove(list.size() - 1); // get the last
    }
}
long time = System.nanoTime() - start;
System.out.println("TIntArrayList push&pop " + values + " repeated "+runs+" times took " + time / 1000000 + " ms.");
```

prints

```
TIntArrayList push&pop 10000000 repeated 10 times took 577 ms.
```

Your biggest overhead is likely to be object allocation.  To speed this up I suggest you look at ways to minimise it.  BTW: You should test how long it take with different integers.

Comment: The list I want should store any type of object (I'm using it to manipulate graphs), however the performance of `TIntArrayList` is awesome.

Comment: I have included ArrayList in my answer.

Comment: It is fast, but my list also has to perform well in operations like segmenting the list and concatenating the segments into new lists. Would you recommend the ArrayList or a LinkedList?

Comment: ArrayList is the easiest to partition as it support random access.  However if you are trying to break up the work between multiple threads you are better off using an ExecutorService for batches of work.

Comment: An ExecutorService can be created with N thread and you give it tasks and it will queue these and process them as threads become free.  Here is an example with uses thread affinity. (So threads are assigned to CPUs) http://vanillajava.blogspot.com/2012/01/java-thread-affinity-library-to-support.html

Answer (score 1):

I think that the reason the performance of your list lags that of the `ArrayList` is that you allocate a lot of small objects, whereas `ArrayList` (and `Stack`, [which is based on `Vector`](http://www.docjar.com/html/api/java/util/Stack.java.html)) allocate in much larger chunks.

If you are set on improving performance of this particular piece of code, you could roll your own lookaside list by pre-allocating memory in large chunks, and then partitioning it into `MyList<T>` as needed. Remember, however, that the memory management implications of doing this would be serious: you need to avoid creating blocks that linger in memory for much longer than it is required, causing a de facto memory leak.

Comment: Thanks I will look in to pre-allocating memory for the list.

Comment: @roelio No problem! If you do not need to release the memory allocated to your queue (for example, if you use it to "smooth out" occasional small spikes in the load, so you could afford a few hundred `MyList<T>` objects sitting in a lookaside list forever) your implementation would be much simpler.

Answer (score 1):

There really isn't *all* that much room for improvement, but I would get rid of the `isNil` variable. You could just as easily use a comparison of `tail == null`. This will save you on a couple assignments each iteration.

You won't be able to get away from the object creation (being that you require it to be single linked, and not array based), but you can reduce the assignment count.